# Use value of a variable as a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I want to use value of a variable as a variable in JavaScript.

```
$.each(devicename, function(index, value) {
     // i am getting qwerty12, qwerty23 , qwerty34, qwerty45 and qwerty56 for
     // 5 iteration of loop. and i want make marker_qwerty12 , marker_qwerty23 ..
     // object of marker. so i need to use append value of index with "marker_"
     // and make "marker_qwerty12 , .. .." object of marker.
   }
);
```

How I can do this ?

Comment: Yo, do this `var foo = index` and you ahve a var with index assigned to it? `:)` or give more context and code we might help you out!

Comment: you can't do that... unless you are trying to access the property of an object

Comment: not sure what you're asking (`index` is already a variable...).  can you provide more explanation?

Comment: Are you trying to use variable variables? Use an object as a hashmap instead.

Comment: How does your devicename look like?

Comment: next time when posting some question, please wait for about at least 5 minutes before logging off, responses and replies in SO are very quickly, almost instantly.

Comment: i am getting "qwerty1" for first iteration of loop. I want to make the value "qwerty1" an object of marker for google map. now how I can do this ?

Comment: @Aayu - please update your question with at least first three rows of your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is not that clear but i am guesing that index is the name of a variable ???

in that case u can acces it throw window global variable :

```
$.each(devicename, function(index, value) {
     console.log(window[index]);
   }
);
```

Comment: @Aayu as i said , i'm guessing what you want... to get the correct answer you need to provide some code sample, otherwise this is all you gana get

Comment: thanks @ Exlord it works

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using eval

```
var b = 5;
var a = "b";
console.log(eval(a));// this will output 5
```

Comment: That's a terrible way to do it, though. It's better to avoid the need completely.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Are you an `eval()` Hater?

Comment: @RPM hint: if the variable is not defined in the current scope, it will crawl all surrounding scopes including `window` - apart from the performance implications - are you willing to take the risk?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that **`devicename`** is **element**, **object** or may be **array** that's why i show you following how to access **`index or value`**.

**`$.each`**  function use to loop through each element of the jquery object. So **`index`** and **`value`** is access by using **`this`** keyword.

#### Element Access

```
$("p").each(function(index, value) { 
    console.log('p tag' + index + ':' + $(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QQk35/2/)**

---

#### Array Access

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three"];
jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
       console.log(value);
       console.log(index); 
       console.log(this); 
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QQk35/3/)**

---

#### Object Access

```
var obj = { 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"};
jQuery.each(obj, function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + " ; " + value);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QQk35/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use array and its index value 
var arrayOfVariable={};

```
$.each(devicename, function(index, value) {
     //here I want to use value of index as a variable.
    arrayOfVariable[value]=new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Text!"
});

   }
);
```

Now accessed it by

```
arrayOfVariable['qwerty1']
```

Comment: i am getting "qwerty1" for first iteration of loop. I want to make the value "qwerty1" an object of marker for google map. now how I can do this ?

Comment: i updated my answer please check